# Trying to Create a PHP Variable for post_type that can be referenced Site Wide

Tags: custom-post-types, php, loop, variables, query-variable

I have several sites with several custom PHP widget loops I've created. I would like to reuse these widgets in other areas and site, but with different custom post types.

The only unique thing in each of the widget PHP files are the post type pulling (in the snippet below, it is **post**):

*$home_carousel_query = new WP_Query('post_type=**post**&posts_per_page=-1&order=ASC);
while($home_carousel_query -> have_posts()) : $home_carousel_query -> the_post();*

I've recently started using Sass and I feel the variable method there has to be used in other languages.

**Is there a way in PHP that I can have 1 file with all my variables (i.e. $carouselCPT='post'; $widgetAlpha='CPT1';, etc.) that will pull to other PHP files?**

Originally my functions.php was HUGE with all of my loops and CPTs, so I portioned the PHP out into more manageable files and include each manually:

**include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/functions/widgetCarousel.php' );**

I'm imagining a solution working something like:

**~in variables.php**
    *$carouselCPT = 'post';*

**~in widgetCarousel.php**
    *...WP_Query('post_type=' . $carouselCPT . '....*

The goal is to load all of these widget files into a GIT repository so that if one file needs a change, it will be updated in all sites with that file, instead of having to make the same change 10+ times.

I am new to PHP - I am not sure of where the variables need to be created, how they need to be written, and then what needs to happen in each file where I am declaring the Custom Post Type....

Help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define a constant in wp.config.php or at the beginning of functions.php of your theme

```
if (!defined('CAROUSEL_CPT')) {
  define("CAROUSEL_CPT", "post");
}

WP_Query('post_type='.CAROUSEL_CPT);//....
```